# TextField letters are transparent

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Hello momently I write a little Meme generator App for learning iOS. development. Now I have one problem.  I set for my Textfields

```
let memeTextAttributes:[String:Any] = [
NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor.rawValue: UIColor.black,
NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white,
NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth.rawValue: 4.0,
]

 func setUPTextField (textField : UITextField){
    textField.delegate = textViewDelegate
    textField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
    textField.textAlignment = .center

}
```

Something is wrong with my memeTextAttributes. If I don't set the property my letters are not transperent. It should look like in the picture. But the letter should not be transparent. They should be white with a black border.

Someone any ideas?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a negative value for stroke width, as explained here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1531/_index.html

```
NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth.rawValue: -4.0
```